# How do I display all _changed? methods for an ActiveRecord model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to create a custom method for a model that will evaluate whether certain variables have changed. How can I get a list of these methods separate from the gargantuan list of other regular methods?

Answer (score 0):

I found that I can run the following method in a Rails Console if I've already queried the model's table beforehand. This will only return `:attribute_changed?` if you haven't done this. Try running `Model.first` before running this method.

`Model.instance_methods.select { |method| method.to_s.include?("_changed?") }`

or to sort them, simply add sort:

`Model.instance_methods.sort!.select { |method| method.to_s.include?("_changed?") }`

This managed to reduce one of my models from over 1000 methods down to less than 50. Much easier to read.